# Почему письма с формы contact form 7 отправляются только от пользователя с правами админа?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, плагин, sendmail

Есть сайт на `wordpress` на котором установлен плагин отправки писем [contact form 7](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/). И движок и плагин последних версий, но есть проблема: в 2 из 3 форм письма отправляются и доходят без каких-либо проблем, а с 3ей формы письма доходят только от администратора сайта, причем ошибок не наблюдаю - появляется сообщение об успешной отправке:

```
<p>*Раздел Автокаталога</br>
[select* menu-799 "Автоакcессуары" "Автозвук" "Автомойки" "Автостекла"]</p>
<p>*Контактное лицо<br />[text* your-name] </p>
<p>*Название фирмы (укажите форму собственности)</br>[text* sobstvennost]</p>
<p>*Описание товара, предоставляемых услуг</br>[text* tovar]</p>
<p>*Ваш телефон</br>[tel* tel-240]</p>
<p>*Ваш e-mail<br />[email* your-email] </p>
<p>Адрес фирмы</br>[text adres]</p>
<p>Адрес сайта</br>[text site]</p>
<p>Лицензия</br>[text license]</p>
<p>*УНП</br>[text* unp]</p>
<p>[submit "Отправить"]</p>
```

В чем может быть причина? на хостинге проверили, сказали, что функция php mail работает исправно без каких-либо ошибок..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело было в том, что часть писем спам-фильтр хостинга попадало - добавил инструкцию `[nospam]` в тему письма и стали доходить!  возможно, что это кому-то пригодится